# Giving ORA:12154 Error while opening the connection

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am developing a application where when submit button is hit then a stored procedure (using oracle 11g,toad as client) is called.
I googled and found to use oracle.dataaccess.dll so downloaded from oracle.

My code is

```
string oradb = "Data Source=xyz;User ID=abc;Password=abc;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();
```

Conn.open gives error ORA:12154

iam using  `oracle.dataaccess.client` namespace

Now it may be possible that package i downloaded didnt installed correctly.
please guide to resolve the issue.

Data source iam using is correct and i successfully connected it via tool provided in visual studio 2015.

Comment: Can you provide your connection string and "tnsnames.ora"?

Answer (score 0):

I had oracle package which provide DLL to .net framework. I had successfully installed that package and configured . The only thing was missing that in that installed folder also we have to copy/paste the tnsname.ora file which will rectify the error. Thank You Mrinal Kamboj for your support.